# Data structures for efficient insertions and deletions to large arrays

Tags: arrays, data-structures, tree, spreadsheet, large-data

What are the data structure suitable for efficiently inserting and deleting large chunks?

Retrieval still has to be fast!

Example use case: a very large spreadsheet, with 100,000 rows and a 1000 columns, and we want to insert 200 columns in the middle. We'd have to do an 100,000 insertions, each into a 1000 element array.

It seems like the [rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) is somewhat similar to what I'm looking for, but it's designed for strings; I'm not sure if it's generalizable to a list of arbitrary objects.

B-trees are also interesting, but I don't want to elements in the array to be sorted according to some criteria .. the only sorting is the order I'm inserting them in!

Answer (score 1):

You can use rope for arbitrary objects. Instead of storing substrings in the leaves, you can store whatever you need there.